# Convert `PascalCase` to `strictCamelCase` in TypeScript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Using the builtin [`Uncapitalize<S>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype), you can naively transform a string such as `FooBar` to `fooBar`:

```
const fooBar: Uncapitalize<'FooBar'> = 'fooBar';
```

However, this method falls short when you use class names following the HTML5 convention, such as `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const xmlHttpRequest: Uncapitalize<'XMLHttpRequest'> = 'xMLHttpRequest';
```

Specifically, I'm looking for a type that can:

1. Transform instances of `PascalCase` that contains mutliple conjoined `UPPER_CASE` letters that form an acronym, into a `strictCamelCase` string type that `lowercase`s the acronyms,
2. Without multiple capital letter humps.

For example:

- `XMLHttpRequest` -> `xmlHttpRequest`
- `HTMLAnchorElement` -> `htmlAnchorElement`
- `FOOBaAAr` -> `foobaaAr`

Since I'll be using this to validate code, not transform user input, I don't really care if it's ugly like that last example, because that becomes the consuming developer's problem to fix their naming (:

I know I can use the new template literal types in TypeScript, specifically, using their [inference features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype). However, their examples only show one-sided inference, like `${infer Foo}bar`, & using multiple inference types make seem to make the last one greedy, like `${infer FirstChar}${infer Rest}bar`.

Comment: Please provide all rules which should be applied to this utility type. Meanwhile, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/transformation-utils)

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what to do with various possible edge cases in the question (not just in the self-answer).  I'd suggest something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3oPAm) but I don't know if it works for your needs.  If so I'm happy to write up an answer (but only after the question actually says what to do); if not, where does it fail?

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions, I've added cases. I like your solution @jcalz, if multiple capital letter humps weren't a requirement, it would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion on the type level to get around the greediness problem.

```
type StrictCase<S extends string> =
  S extends `${
    infer P1 extends Uppercase<string>
  }${
    infer P2 extends Uppercase<string>
  }${
    infer P3
  }`
    ? `${Lowercase<P1>}${StrictCase<`${P2}${P3}`>}`
    : S extends `${infer P1}${infer P2}`
    ? P2 extends ''
      ? Lowercase<P1>
      : `${P1}${StrictCase<P2>}`
    : S;

type StrictPascalCase<S extends string> = Capitalize<StrictCase<S>>
type StrictCamelCase<S extends string> = Uncapitalize<StrictCase<S>>;
```

In the `StrictCase<S>` type:

1. If there is two conjoined uppercase letters -> `FOOBar`

   1. This is the set of uppercase letters that were problematic in the question
      **Transform the first char into lowercase, then pass the rest back into `StrictCase<S>`.** -> **f**`StrictCamelCaseImpl<'OOBar'>`
2. Else if there is only one letter left -> `r`

   1. **Lowercase & return it.** -> `r`
3. Else if there are at least two letters -> `Bar`

   1. These can be any combination of cases
      **Return the first char as is, then pass the rest back into `StrictCase<S>`.** -> **B**`StrictCamelCaseImpl<'ar'>`
4. Else -> `ar`

   1. Return as is -> `ar`

Then, after that is done, to normalise into either `camelCase` or `PascalCase`, it's just a matter of `Capitalize<S>` or `Uncapitalize<S>`, which transforms the first letter either into `UPPER_CASE` or `lowercase`.